# Set the position of a UIBarButtonItem Programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, positioning, uibarbuttonitem

How would I be able to set the position of a UIBarButtonItem? Like, I would like to set it to be on either the very right of a UIToolbar or the very left depending on a state.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You do not set directly the position of a [UIBarButtonItem](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in an [UIToolbar](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Instead you defined the items' order and put flexible space on the left or on the right.

What you can do is:

- Create the UIBarButtonItem you want to place (button 1).
- Create an UIBarButtonItem of type `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` (button 2).
- If you want to put the button on the left, create an array with (button 1) and (button 2) and pass it to the UIToolbar by using the `setItems:animated:` method.
- If you want to put the button on the right, create an array with (button 2) and (button 1) and pass it to the UIToolbar by using the `setItems:animated:` method.

Answer (score 3):

I hope it helps you...

```
UIToolbar* keyboardDoneButtonView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[keyboardDoneButtonView sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem* PrevButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:105 target:nil  action:nil]; //<
UIBarButtonItem*  NextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:106  target:nil action:nil]; //>
UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)];

UIBarButtonItem* flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *fake = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil] ;

[keyboardDoneButtonView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: PrevButton,fake, NextButton,fake,flexSpace,fake,doneButton,nil] animated:YES];
```

Link explains **Bar Button Item** Methods and Arguments
[https://developer.apple.com/library.....](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/BarButtonItem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-CH2-SW1) Use **Fake** Item to get exact pinch location on Button...